# How to make installable file from php+mysql website for standalone?

Tags: php

I made the exe file from php+mysql site and it has a header already send data problem, so how to solved this problem or which is the best way to create installable file for standalone from php+mysql site.

I have made exe file trough php desktop method.

Comment: "it has a header already send data problem" - I think I know what you mean, but can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: That sounds like an error which would have been visible during testing, before you compiled it to an exe. So fix the bug in the source code and then make a new exe. If it's the "headers already sent" error, you can easily Google the error message to get detailed explanations of what it means and what can cause it. It doesn't sound like it's anything to do with the executable itself. If you disagree you would need to provide a [mre] of the issue so we can do further diagnosis. See also [ask]